# Agrometeorology questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions related to agrometeorology on topic or not ? It could encompass crop yield forecast in response to climate change. Ways to prevent a hailstorm battering crops etc. Are these on topic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that crops are planted by humans for their benefit, crops are still biological 'entities' that are subject to the laws of science.

Crops also cover a significant area of the Earth's surface & hence not only are affected by climate & weather but they also influence climate & weather. Deforestation of the Amazon has had one impact on climate. The replacement of the Amazon forest by grass lands and grazing cattle has had another. If the Amazon forest was replaced by concrete and bitumen urban development that would have had a different climatic affect.

Crops are an integral part of the anthropogenic altered bio-system of the Earth - hence they are a part of the human altered Earth Science of this planet. In my opinion question on agro-meteorology are on topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the question is framed with a weather angle, I see no reason why agrometeorology wouldn't be on topic. [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com) has an [agriculture](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agriculture) tag to address the biology angle of agronomy so it would make sense that we deal with the meteorology angle (and why not also the pedology angle as well by the way). I'm guessing that, for more concrete questions on agriculture, [Gardening and Landscapes SE](http://https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) and [Sustainable Living SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) are good alternatives as well though I'm not familiar with what is on-topic or not on those two SE sites.

Comment: I was referring to crop yield forecasts due to climate change and whether hail storms can be averted by silver iodide flares etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree that agrometeorology is on topic - as it links into the 'anthropocene' notion that our land use is affecting the climate (and soils etc).  Such questions, framed to be specifically related to a 'traditional' aspect of ES would definitely be on topic.